# Cakephp 2 render multiple elements from 1 controller function

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I call a Js link to update a product status (active/inactive) via ajax

```
echo $this->Js->link('[X]',
array('action' => 'deactivate', $p['Product']['id']),
array('before'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeIn'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#loading')->effect('fadeOut'),
'update'=> '#'.$divString));
```

Once the ajax is made, a table row is hidden via the update.
The view is rendered using

```
$this->render('index_ajax_empty_table_row', 'ajax');
```

Now i need to update a my menu (via ajax) that holds the categories and counts of active products. So from the same contoller action is am trying

```
$this->render('index_ajax_menu', 'ajax');
```

The code will only render the first item or the wrong one in the wrong place.

How do i define multiple success  and tell which element to render for each div?

Comment: Can you show the whole function?